# Inserting Data into Sql Using Java Netbeans

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I want to insert input given by user into Sql Table using Java, but dont know how many coloumn is need.

eg.

```
insert into table_name values('"+id+"','"+name+"')
```

this query is not going to work because I don't know the column name i.e ID, name.

I want the query that is universal for any inserting data.

Comment: What if the table does not have an "id" and/or a "name" column? Why do you want to have a "universal query"? Seems very odd ...

Comment: I want to make a program in which user enter the table name and the user will get two option 1) Select 2) Insert.... For Select I used ResultMetaData but for inserting I dont know how much is coloumn number, tables data types, name and all. So how to do insert query?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any universal query.

If you dont know column name than you can find name of the column by using meta data.

You can get meta data of the connections (database)

```
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
```

You can also get list of the tables.

```
String   catalog          = null;
String   schemaPattern    = null;
String   tableNamePattern = null;
String[] types            = null;

ResultSet result = databaseMetaData.getTables(
    catalog, schemaPattern, tableNamePattern, types );

while(result.next()) {
    String tableName = result.getString(3);
}
```

Listing column name in table.

```
String   catalog           = null;
String   schemaPattern     = null;
String   tableNamePattern  = "my_table";
String   columnNamePattern = null;


ResultSet result = databaseMetaData.getColumns(
    catalog, schemaPattern,  tableNamePattern, columnNamePattern);

while(result.next()){
    String columnName = result.getString(4);
    int    columnType = result.getInt(5);
}
```

In this way you can find column name and can create query dynamically.

Comment: Thank You! Nikesh Joshi for helping me. I appreicate your help.

Comment: Please select my answer as best answer, plz

Answer (score 0):

As per my need I tried this code. I HOPE IT WORKED FOR ALL.

void getTableInput(String tname, String dname) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        this.tname = tname;
        this.dname = dname;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String conURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=" + this.dname + ";user=JT_DATA;password=1234";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conURL);

    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + this.tname);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int colNo = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    String colName[] = new String[colNo];




    String[] get_User_Input = new String[100];
    for (int i = 1; i <=colNo; i++) 
    {
        colName[i-1] = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i);
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(colName) + " : ");
        get_User_Input[i-1] = s.next();
    }
    String store="";
    for(int i=0;i<colNo;i++)
    {
        store += "'"+get_User_Input[i]+"',";
    }
    store = store.substring(0,store.length() -1);
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into "+this.tname+" values ("+ store +")");
    pst.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Data Inserted");

}
```

But the problem with this is that. This can only insert String Datatype.

Comment: Please read the JDBC tutorial on how to use a `PreparedStatement` properly